# Kafka broker is not available from localhost

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have installed `kafka_2.11-1.1.0` and set advertised listener to `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<my-ip>:9092` (in `$KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties`).

I can connect and write to my kafka using java code and see my cluster via `kafka-tool` from another server but I can't write messages to my topic from my local machine (the one that I have installed kafka cluster on it).

I have also tried to set listeners value to `listeners = PLAINTEXT://:9092` but there is no change. What should I do to my kafka to make it reachable and writable from both outside and inside of the localhost?

Comment: "I can't write messages to my topic from my local machine" -> do you get an error message? How are you trying to write them?

Comment: I try to write an application like the example described here:
https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-producer-and-consumer-example
I mean from a java code.

Comment: Can you show a netstat output for port 9092? And again, are there errors you're getting?

Comment: I used telned from this server to itself (`telnet localhost 9092`) and it tells me `Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.` and after pressing enter it says `Connection to localhost closed by foreign host.`. What should I do with netstat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by changing my code's `org.apache.kafka` library from version `1.1.0` to version `2.1.0`.

I mention that all of these libraries were imported (downloaded) and used via `mvnrepository.com`.

Also, our kafka producer and consumer code pattern were written using this article:
`https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-producer-and-consumer-example`.

Comment: I hope other developers, not to have such mind blowing issues in the future!!

Comment: I'm not sure but, maybe that's because when you upgrade your kafka version you might need to upgrade your libraries version too.

Answer (score 10):

In the server.properties use these two following properties

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<your ip>:9092
```

Comment: It didn't help. I must say that I use solaris 10 and this issue happens just on this machine.

Comment: Check if your machine is behind a firewall that's blocking incoming connection on port 9092.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that I don't have any networking/firewall issue. I insisted in the beginning that I can connect from outside.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is useful

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in the below following links, it may be helpful for your scenario,

- [Kafka access inside and outside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53247553/kafka-access-inside-and-outside-docker)
- [Kafka Listeners - Explained](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/)

Comment: My issue is with internal connections not the external ones. When I set my ip or localhost or 127.0.0.1 kafka clients are not able to connect to my kafka broker.

Comment: Then, have you checked the hosts file of your system? Is ip or locahost or 127.0.0.1 reachable via ping?

Comment: I have checked them again and all of them are alive and reachable.