# How we can map docker ip in external application

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I installed zookeeper and Kafka using docker with help of following link
https://crunchytechbytz.wordpress.com/2018/01/28/install-apache-kafka-in-docker-container/

Now I want to publish a message on one of the topic in kafka. 
If I get ip of docker kafka by using the following command.

```
docker network inspect kafka-net
```

I use this ip in my application. I am able to publish message to kafka queue. How we can do the automatic mapping.

I tried one-way mapping docker container port to mapping outer port. This makes it very slow and After this consumer also not able to consume this.

Comment: I would say that this is the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53247553/kafka-access-inside-and-outside-docker
Someone may mark this as duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Kafka from outside of your application you must expose the port (as you said mapping to an outer-port, for example) or directly running in the network mode host `--net=host`.

**While accessing you need to give the outer port and not the inner port.**

For testing Kafka connection try:

```
telnet <ip_of_your_outer_machine>:<outer_port>
```

If you are able to telnet, then you are able to connect to it from outside.

If you choose `--net=host` then you should be able to access Kafka with the inner port (since in this mode you are outer port and inner port are same).

Answer (score -1):

Can you paste what is inside your kafka container? (docker inspect kafka)
If there is nothing on your port mapping, you need to run docker image of kafka with -p parameter which expose port to the outside world. -p have syntax like this: "-p outside_port:inside_port" and when you want to ping kafka you will ping with outside port.

Comment: Kafka clients require more than just a simple port mapping