# No such host where i connect to kafka broker on server via port forwarding

Tags: docker, go, apache-kafka, docker-for-mac

I have following problem:
i have running instance of kafka broker on server in k8s. 
This broker i have port forwarded to localhost kubectl port-forward kafka-broker-0 9104.

I'am sure it works, because I try it from my python app, but if i try example in go from internet

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"

    kingpin "gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2"

    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
)

var (
    brokerList        = kingpin.Flag("brokerList", "List of brokers to connect").Default("localhost:9104").Strings()
    topic             = kingpin.Flag("topic", "Topic name").Default("important").String()
    partition         = kingpin.Flag("partition", "Partition number").Default("0").String()
    offsetType        = kingpin.Flag("offsetType", "Offset Type (OffsetNewest | OffsetOldest)").Default("-1").Int()
    messageCountStart = kingpin.Flag("messageCountStart", "Message counter start from:").Int()
)

func main() {
    kingpin.Parse()
    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.Consumer.Return.Errors = true
    brokers := *brokerList
    master, err := sarama.NewConsumer(brokers, config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := master.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
    consumer, err := master.ConsumePartition(*topic, 0, sarama.OffsetOldest)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    signals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signals, os.Interrupt)
    doneCh := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case err := <-consumer.Errors():
                fmt.Println(err)
            case msg := <-consumer.Messages():
                *messageCountStart++
                fmt.Println("Received messages", string(msg.Key), string(msg.Value))
            case <-signals:
                fmt.Println("Interrupt is detected")
                doneCh <- struct{}{}
            }
        }
    }()
    <-doneCh
    fmt.Println("Processed", *messageCountStart, "messages")
}
```

i've got error

```
panic: dial tcp: lookup host.docker.internal: no such host

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/anonymous/go/src/pr1/kafka-consumer.go:37 +0x33b
exit status 2
```

pls, where can be a problem?

Comment: are you running the code inside a docker container? If the answer is yes, did you forward the port from your machine to the container?

Comment: Quite simple, your process can not resolve the hostname `host.docker.internal`. If you use Kubernetes, there should be a service which exports Kubernetes to the rest of your cluster, usually under a cluster ip and the hostname `<servicename>.<namespace>.<clusterdomain>`. Try to inspect your Kafka service -- it should give you all required information.

Comment: What does the Python code look like? Where are you getting the difference?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53247553/kafka-access-inside-and-outside-docker
On first request, Kafka returns the address data should be sent to. This address is only visible inside the docker world, thus your host cannot connect. Solution: configure Kafka to return other address for connections from outside network (advertise listener).

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple, your process can not resolve the hostname `host.docker.internal`.

### Go program running in a pod on k8s

Assuming you have your Go program running in a container on the Kubernetes cluster, you need to take a few measures as detailed below.

If you use Kubernetes, there should be a service which exports Kubernetes to the rest of your cluster, usually under a cluster ip and the hostname `<servicename>.<namespace>.<clusterdomain>`.

Below you can see how to approach that:

```sh
$ kubectl --namespace=mynamespace get svc
NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)              AGE
centraldb-cockroachdb          ClusterIP   None             <none>        26257/TCP,8080/TCP   21d
centraldb-cockroachdb-public   ClusterIP   10.110.105.151   <none>        26257/TCP,8080/TCP   21d

$ kubectl get --namespace=mynamespace service centraldb-cockroachdb-public -o json | jq ".spec"
{
  "clusterIP": "10.110.105.151",
  "ports": [
    {
      "name": "grpc",
      "port": 26257,
      "protocol": "TCP",
      "targetPort": "grpc"
    },
    {
      "name": "http",
      "port": 8080,
      "protocol": "TCP",
      "targetPort": "http"
    }
  ],
  "selector": {
    "app.kubernetes.io/component": "cockroachdb",
    "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "centraldb",
    "app.kubernetes.io/name": "cockroachdb"
  },
  "sessionAffinity": "None",
  "type": "ClusterIP"
}
```

As you can see, I run a cockroachdb, and its public grpc port is available via 10.110.105.151:26257, while its http port is available via 10.110.105.151:8080.

Now, how do we find out our DNS name?

We deploy a little helper into the same namespace.

First, we create a yaml file bb.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox:latest
    command:
      - sleep
      - &quot;7200&quot;
    name: busybox
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Then, we apply it **to the same namespace** as the service we want to get the DNS name for:

```sh
$ kubectl --namespace=mynamespace apply -f bb.yaml 
pod/busybox created
```

Now, we can find the full DNS name of your service via:

```sh
$ kubectl exec --namespace=mynamespace busybox -- nslookup centraldb-cockroachdb-public
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      centraldb-cockroachdb-public
Address 1: 10.110.105.151 centraldb-cockroachdb-public.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local
```

(Note that the IP dresses and DNS names obviously can be different in your installation).

So, we should be able to reach the CockroachDB web via "centraldb-cockroachdb-public.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local:8080" *from within the cluster*.

## Go program running outside k8s

What to do here heavily depends on your installation. If you are using Docker for Desktop, as I assume, the easiest way is to expose the deployment in question:

```sh
$ kubectl port-forward svc/$yourServiceName $localport:$serviceport
```

This would make the http port of the service "centraldb-cockroachdb-public" available via localhost:9000:

```
$ kubectl port-forward --namespace=mynamespace svc/centraldb-cockroachdb-public 9000:8080
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9000 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:9000 -> 8080
```

Now, we open another shell and call http://localhost:9000:

```sh
$ curl -sI  http://localhost:9000
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://localhost:9000/
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 12:17:09 GMT
```

To make this permanent, you either need to change the type of service to [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or use what Kubernetes calls a ["LoadBalancer"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/).

Comment: @cricket_007 This was just an example. A Kubernetes loadbalancer has a different meaning -- hence the Link. It is IP based.

Comment: Even so, Kafka clients are required to directly communicate to the brokers, and thus cannot only reach out to the LB

Comment: @cricket_007 That would mean that there is literally no way to provide a Kafka instance via Kubernetes, since the only way other than using node ports to expose a service is a Kubernetes Loadbalancer. I find that hard to blieve, but will test that. Especially since the bitnami chart explicitly calls for a LoadbalancerIP.

Comment: Haven't used that chart. I'm just saying how the Kafka protocol works. Hence why projects like this exist - https://github.com/grepplabs/kafka-proxy

Comment: @cricket_007 Seem like we were both right -- kinda. The chart exposes each member of the cluster with its own Loadbalancer IP...